# Copying over from a string of words to a structure in c.

Tags: c, structure

i'm starting to use structures with very basic knowledge in my class and i am having trouble understanding how to copy from a string using strtok to a wordlist in a structure. This is my code so far but when I run it all I get are segmentation faults. Also afterwards i would like to print the words in the word list along with getting their lengths.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct myWord
{
    char Word[21];
    int Length;
} WordList[20];

int main(){
  int i;
  char myString[] = "the cat in the hat jumped over the lazy fox";

  strcpy(WordList[0].Word, strtok(myString, " "));
  WordList[0].Length = strlen(WordList[0].Word);

  for(i=1; i<11; i++){
      strcpy(WordList[i].Word, strtok(NULL, " "));
      WordList[i].Length = strlen(WordList[i].Word);
  }
  for(i=0; i<11; i++){
    printf("%s\n", WordList[i].Word); 
  }
}
```

Comment: One problem is that the input only has 10 words, so the `< 11` (two places) should be `< 10`, but even better would be to check the return value from `strtok` so you know when `strtok` has reached the end.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will be better solution:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct myWord
{
    char Word[21];
    int Length;
} WordList[20];

int main(){
  int i;
  char myString[] = "the cat in the hat jumped over the lazy fox";
  char *ptr;
  ptr = strtok(myString, " ");
  for(i=0; i<9 && ptr != NULL; i++){
      ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
      strcpy(WordList[i].Word, ptr);
      WordList[i].Length = strlen(WordList[i].Word);
  }
  for(i=0; i<11; i++){
    printf("%s\n", WordList[i].Word); 
  }
}
```